# I have a problem with qsort in c while sorting database file?

Tags: c, file, sorting, qsort, fgetc

I am new in programming, I want to do database sorting using `qsort` function in `C`.

we have a file of 100 people, I want to sort it by their last names by reading the data from text file into database variable of 100 people and with `struct`. I'm new in this.

This is my code:

```
  int compare(const void *pa,const void *pb)
{
  char *Ina = *((person_t*)pa)->last_name;
  char *Inb = *((person_t*)pb)->last_name;
   return strcmp(Ina,Inb);
};


    while(fgetc(fp)!= EOF)
    {
        strcpy(dbasepeople[ctr].last_name,str1);
        strcpy(dbasepeople[ctr].first_name,str2);
        strcpy(dbasepeople[ctr].city_name,str3);
    ++ ctr;  
    }
```

so i got this error or output
which is not i wants.

```
297608 ���� ��e2� -1674750400 0                                                                                                
6297698 ���� ��e2� -1674750400 0                                                                                                
6297788 ���� ��e2� -1674750400 0                                                                                                
6297878 ���� ��e2� -1674750400 0                                                                                                
6297968 ���� ��e2� -1674750400 0                                                                                                
6298058 ���� ��e2� -1674750400 0                                                                                                
6298148 ���� ��e2� -1674750400 0                                                                                                
6298238 ���� ��e2� -1674750400 0                                                                                                
6298328 ���� ��e2� -1674750400 0                                                                                                
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

the warnings i'm getting are

```
main.c:16:15: warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]                       
main.c:17:15: warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]                       
Before sorting:                                                                                                          
6295808 ���� P|�t� -1 0                                                                                                  
6295898 ���� P|�t� 873305664 0                                                                                           
6295988 ���� P|�t� 873305664 0                                                                                           
6296078 ���� P|�t� 873305664 0                                                                                           
6296168 ���� P|�t� 873305664 0
```

Comment: Don't you get any diagnostics from the compiler? Please compile with `-Werror`!

Comment: The reason to the crash will give a warning

Comment: Did you try running the program line by line in a debugger while monitoring the values of all variables to see whether they have the values that you expect? And did you use the debugger to determine in which line the program is causing the segmentation fault?

Comment: The first format is `%d` but the first item printed is a string.

Comment: done %d warnings @stark

Comment: Thanks to Everyone. after spending 4 hours finally i am able to understand fully and my program is running perfectly. Thanks every one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will try to explain some pointer and array concepts and tie it to your solution. To make it easier to think about pointers and memory space I like to compare pointers to house addresses and memory space to houses/notes, I think it's helpful for beginners.

`char *Ina = *((person_t*)pa)->last_name;
 char *Inb = *((person_t*)pb)->last_name;`

`char *Ina =` 
Let the there be a pointer called Ina(think of it as a home address) to something that is of type char(in the house lives a char).

`*((person_t*)pa)->last_name;`

Using the * on another pointer means go to the house of the home address and give me what is inside. Now you have defined the `struct person_t` which says what kind of stuff will be inside the house. Among other things you have said that the `person_t` house will contain a `char last_name[30]`. What you are saying here is that the `person_t` house will contain a note(called last_name) with an address to a note that contains a character and the following 29 notes in the house will also contain exactly one character.

When using `((person_t *) pa) -> last_name` we are saying go to the house with home address `pa`(which is a `person_t` house). When we are in that house we want to get the note(called `last_name`, containing another address) and return what it contains.

When you use the `*((person_t *) pa)` you are going into the house pa and you will get the character scribbled down on the first note in the house. At this point we have a real char to deal with, there are no addresses to follow.

Now let us look at the second issue

```
   char str1[30],str2[30],str3[30];

   FILE *fp;
   fp=fopen("words.txt","r");
   if(fp==NULL)
   { 
   printf("\n Cannot open the file \n");
   exit(0);
   }
   while(fgetc(fp)!= EOF)
   {
       strcpy(dbasepeople[ctr].last_name,str1);
       strcpy(dbasepeople[ctr].first_name,str2);
       strcpy(dbasepeople[ctr].city_name,str3);
   ++ ctr;  
   }
```

What does this mean?
`char str1[30],str2[30],str3[30];`
Here we are saying that there should be 3 notes (`str1`, `str2`, `str3`) each containing an address to a house with a character, and the subsequent 29 houses should also contain exactly one character. We never said what character the house contains though. This means that there could be any kind of junk in the houses at this point.

`strcpy(dbasepeople[ctr].last_name,str1);`

Now what `strcpy` does is that it goes to the house of the addresses given by the second arguments and assumes that there are going to be several houses in a row containing characters and go through all of them until there is a house containing only a 0, or it reached an upper limit. Now it will use similar logic to fill up the houses referred to by the first argument.
Now you need to ask yourself, what is actually going to be in `str1` when you start reading from it?

`fgetc()` will read and return characters from the textfile.
Think about how you use `fgetc()` here and what you do with the characters that it returns. Do you ever actually use them?

This is my first answer on SO so I would appreciate feedback!
I hope I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue might be in the compare function. The last_name reference is a pointer to char, being declared as an array. You don’t need the star - which simply gets the first char in the array.